# area and perimeter of this figure

Tags: geometry, area

What are the **area** and **perimeter** of the union of the circles in the picture, where $r$ is the radius of both circles?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the area and perimeter of the *intersection*, the *union*, or the *difference* between the two circles?

Comment: @wltrup sorry, i forgot to mention. I mean the union

Comment: Ok, fair enough. By the way, you don't need to make the entire question **bold**.

Comment: @wltrup copy that :D

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Is there a particular step you're having trouble with?

Comment: @wltrup Well, the area obviously is $A = \pi * r^2 + (\pi * r^2 - x)$. My problem is, that I dont know how to calculate the area of an circle-segment like this (because the segment is not a triangle, but elliptic)

Comment: You can draw an equilateral  triangle using the line you have drawn as a base, and with the third vertex at a point of intersection of the two circles. That should be enough to get the angle and hence everything you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit busy right now, so - for now - I'll just post a hint. If the hint isn't sufficient for you to figure out the answer on your own and if no one else answers your question in detail, I'll post a detailed answer later.

**Hint:** Try to find the value of the angle $a$ in the figure. Then decompose the area and perimeter of the intersection of the two circles into those of more fundamental shapes, like arcs and segments and triangles.

[image]

---

**Detailed answer**

First, note that the length of the segment $\overline{AC}$ equals $r$ because $A$ is the centre of the circle on the left and $C$ is on that circle. Similarly, the length of the segment $\overline{BC}$ also equals $r$ because $B$ is the centre of the other circle and $C$ is on that circle as well. That means the triangle $ABC$ is **equilateral**.

Now, an equilateral triangle has all 3 of its internal angles equal to 60 degrees, or $\pi/3$ radians, so $a = \pi/3$ radians. With that bit of information, we can now proceed to find first the perimeter then the area of the intersection and, with those, the perimeter and area of the union.

**Perimeter**

Focus your attention on the arc opposite to $A$, from $B$ to $C$. That's an arc of a circumference, with an angle $a = \pi/3$ radians and a radius $r$. What's the length of that arc? Well, from the definition of radian, we know that the length of that arc is $s = ra = \pi r/3$. How many arcs do we have in the intersection? Four. Therefore, the perimeter of the intersection is $4 \times \pi r/3 = (4/3)\pi r$.

Now, the perimeters of the union is the sum of the perimeters of the circles (thus 2 times $2\pi r$) minus the perimeter of the intersection. Thus,

> $$
> \mbox{perimeter of the union } = \frac{8}{3}\,\pi r
> $$

**Area**

First, the area of the triangle $ABC$. It's an equilateral triangle of side $r$ so its area is $(1/2) \times r \times r\sin a = (\sqrt{3}/4)\,r^2$, because $\sin a = \sin(\pi/3) = \sqrt{3}/2$.

Now, in my view, a neat way to get the area of that sliver between the segment $\overline{AC}$ and the **arc** $\overset{\frown}{AC}$ is to recall that a circle inscribes a regular hexagon whose side equals the radius. That hexagon has 6 of the triangles we just talked about, leaving 6 slivers to fill the circle. Thus,
$$
\mbox{area of 1 sliver } =
\frac{\pi r^2 - 6 \times \mbox{area of } \Delta ABC}{6} =
(\frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4})\,r^2
$$

But we have 4 slivers and 2 triangles in the intersection, so
$$
\mbox{area of intersection } =
4\,(\frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4})\,r^2 + 2\,(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\,r^2) =
(\frac{2\pi}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\,r^2
$$

Then, finally, the area of the union is twice the area of one circle minus the area of the intersection, so

> $$
> \mbox{area of the union } = (\frac{4\pi}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\,r^2
> $$

Comment: ahhh, got it. Was thinking to complicated

Answer (score 0):

WRONG: My result so far is

$$
A(r) = 2\pi r^2 - \frac{2\pi r^2}{\frac{180°}{\alpha}} +\frac{r^2\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
with
$$
\alpha = 2 \arccos{\frac{r^2}{2}}
$$

Little clarification: $\alpha = 2a$ and $r = \overline{AC} = \overline{BC}$ (if you look at the drawing in the answer of wltrup)

Edit (RIGHT):

$$
A(r) = 2\pi r^2 - \frac{2\pi r^2}{3} + \frac{r^2\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$

Comment: You got the area right but your $\alpha$ is incorrect. For a detailed solution, see my answer above.

Comment: @wltrup Yes, you're right. I chose antoher approach. But still yours and mine are giving different results for $r = 1$ (for $r = 1$ my  $\alpha$ equals even with the wrong equation $=120° or  \frac{2\pi}{3}$)

Comment: I don't understand what your $\alpha$ is supposed to represent. In any case, it's dimensionally incorrect since $r^2$ has the dimensions of area (say, meters squared) and you can't take the arc-cosine of an area. Your result for the area of the union is correct, however, since $a = 60^{\circ}$ and you get the same result as I did.

Comment: I see now what your $\alpha$ represents. It's the angle from $C$ to its counterpart on the other side, hence $2a$.

Comment: The correct expression for $\alpha$ is $\alpha = 2\arccos(1/2)$. No $r^2$.

Comment: @wltrup I figured this because $\cos{a} = \frac{adjacent\ side}{hypotenuse} = \frac{\frac{r}{2}}{r}$ and I thought arccos is the same as cos^-1 (as on my calculator) Edit:  Seems like my error was that $\frac{\frac{r}{2}}{r} = 0,5$

Comment: Yes, sorry, misread your last comment. Indeed, your mistake was in the division of $r/2$ by $r$. The result should be $1/2$.

Comment: Found the error: I substracted the intersection twice, but you only need to substract it once to get the area.

Comment: I'm happy to see that you're still working on your own solution despite the fact that I provided a detailed solution already. Other people might simply give up. Kudos!